# C++ Qt: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to remind myself some C++, and also learn about Qt.

I am working on Windows. I have installed Qt (5.1.0), MinGW (g++ 4.6.2), Gnu Make (3.81).

I am trying to compile a simple Qt app. The most basic case is this:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtGui>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {               
    QApplication app(argc, argv);                  
    QTextStream cout(stdout);                               
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The project file is:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = example1
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += fac1.cpp
QT += gui widgets core
```

When I run

```
qmake
```

it generates the Makefile.

But then with `make` I get this:

```
C:\src\early-examples\example1>make
make -f Makefile.Release
make[1]: Entering directory `C:/src/early-examples/example1'
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o release\example1.exe release/fac1.o  -LC:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\\5.1.0\msvc2012_64\lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -llibEGL -llibGLESv2 -lgdi32 -luser32
release/fac1.o:fac1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QApplicationC1ERiPPci'
release/fac1.o:fac1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x37): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QApplicationD1Ev'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [release\example1.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/src/early-examples/example1'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing compilers here. Why are you using visual studio libraries with gcc?

Comment: I am trying to use g++, but there might me some settings/env variables that I am not aware of. How can you tell?

Comment: Or are you saying I have to use Visual Studio to use Qt?

Comment: You have "-LC:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\\5.1.0\msvc2012_64\lib" in the output you posted.

Comment: Yes. You should have a mingw version.

Comment: Ok I am going the the Qt page to try to find it. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Please consider turning your comment into an answer, I would like to accept it.

Comment: Thanks. I assume you got by the problem on the deleted comment.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the one I was aiming at ;) It is late here.

Comment: And the other deleted comment - yes :) lol. I am tired. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is you appear to be using Visual Studio 2012 libraries for your mingw builds. You need to link to the mingw compiled Qt instead.

Comment: Yes. I downloaded (from http://qt-project.org/downloads) Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB) instead of Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 666 MB). Works fine now!

Comment: This is the reason why there are so many Qt binary releases on the downloads. Even mixing different visual studio versions can give you problems.

Answer (score 1):

Add "greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets" into your .pro file